# How to code Java APIs with Playframework

Tags: java, playframework

I want to write Java API code using playframework! (I'm using the Eclipse IDE.)

- What would a sample API look like for insertion and selection?
- How do I assign URLs in a routes file?

Answer (score 0):

This answer applies to version 3 of the Play framework.

Here is a sample route file configuration to show a page. In this example, you can visit http://yoursite.com/1 , which will call `controllers.Application.show("1")`.

```
# Extract the page parameter from the path.
# i.e. http://myserver.com/index
GET   /:page                controllers.Application.show(page)
```

**SELECTION**

Here is the corresponding show method definition in the controllers.Application controller:

```
public Result show(String page) {
    String content = Page.getContentOf(page);
    response().setContentType("text/html");
    return ok(content);
}
```

**INSERTION**

For insertion, check out the ["Form submission and validation"](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/3.0.x/JavaForms) and ["Working with JSON"](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/3.0.x/JavaJsonActions) sections of the documentation. There are examples there; sorry for not adding them here, but these are more complicated for this short format.

Source, and more information: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/3.0.x/JavaRouting